# Android Dynamic Custom List view

Tags: android

I am retrieving a list of countries  with offers from a sqlite database.

I want to display these offers in a ListView which should display by country. 
For example:  suppose India has 5 offers, then it should display: India and then all 5 offers; then other country and their offers and so on..

The data should be displayed with a check box. If the check box is unchecked, the item should be highlighted. 
the code are as follows

```
_arrayAdapterActiveCards = new ArrayAdapter<Card>(this, R.layout.active_card_list_item, _activeUserCards)
{
    LayoutInflater layout_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());

    @Override
    public Card getItem(int position)
        {
            return _activeUserCards.get(position);
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            Card select_card = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null)
                {
                    convertView = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.active_card_list_item, null);
                }

            String selected_card = select_card.getBankName() + " - " + select_card.getCardName().replaceAll("\\s+$", "");

            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.card_name_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.active_card_name_view);
            holder.card_name_view.setText(selected_card);
            holder._checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.active_card_checkbox);
            holder._checkBox // here implement check box facility
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            String savedItems = null;

                            if (!_listViewForActiveCards.isItemChecked(position))
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Value of position  = " + position);
                                }

                            _arrayAdapterActiveCards.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                });

            return convertView;
        }

    class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView card_name_view;
            CheckBox _checkBox;
        }
};

_arrayAdapterActiveCards.setNotifyOnChange(true);
_listViewForActiveCards.setAdapter(_arrayAdapterActiveCards);
for (int i = 0; i < _noOfCountry; i++)
{
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    _fragmentLayoutActiveCard = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null);
    _fragmentLayoutActiveCard.setId(i);
    _lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.countryAndCardListLayout);
    _countryText[i] = new TextView(this);
    _countryText[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    _countryText[i].setText(_countryName[i].toUpperCase());
    _countryText[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    _lLayout.addView(_countryText[i]);
    _lLayout.addView(_fragmentLayoutActiveCard);
    _listViewForActiveCards = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fragmentCardList);
    getCardFromDataBaseTestMethodActiveCard(_countryName[i]);
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried..

Comment: Please look at the code I really need a serious help plz

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

** Please provide code in proper format. It will help you to get your answer correctly and quickly.

Comment: Sir Thanks for such a quick response And I got what I wanted But will you please guide me to get onlick listner event of each check  box in the list and for each checkbox click I can do differnt differnt task

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have understood your question. Display each country and their offers one by one (the info retrieved via database).
For this you may have to implement custom array adapter and display it accordingly.